# Product Report within a time frame in CartThrob

Tags: cartthrob, shopping-cart

I am trying to generate a report in CartThrob that will display individual products sold. 
In the CT order manager when you click on Product Report you get a list of products and how many you have sold of each.

Problem is when you add the date range and generate the report it generates an order report and not a product report.

I want to be able to generate a report that shows how many of Product A | Product B was sold within a time frame.  NOT a report of orders.

Also the product report only shows 23 products, there does not seem to be a way to display all products or filter them at all.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am trying to do the same thing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [**CT Admin**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ct-admin). It's a 3rd Party reporting tool for CartThrob. Might do the trick for you.

> a stand alone store management panel that allows for order and
>   customer management as well as reporting and data export.

Here are details on what the CP looks like for the addon:
http://www.mithra62.com/docs/detail/ct-admin-instructions/